# Modifying lists within lists via list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, nested-loops

how can I get these `loops` and `if statements` into a comprehension?

```
raw = [['-', 'bla'], ['-', 'la'], ['=', 'bla']]

for one in raw:
    if one[0] == '-':
        for two in raw:
            if two[1] == one[1] and two[0] == '=': two[0] = '--'
```

So far:

```
[two+one for two in raw for one in raw]
```

But not sure where to put the if statements:

`if one[0] == '-'` and `if two[1] == one[1] and two[0] == '=': two[0] = '--'`

Comment: What is your desired ouput?

Comment: the example code returns `raw` as `[['-', 'bla'], ['-', 'la'], ['--', 'bla']]`

Comment: I've answered based on your desired output, as your logic is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple list comprehension should be sufficient:

```
raw = [['-', 'bla'], ['-', 'la'], ['=', 'bla']]

res = [['--' if (i != '-') and (['-', j] in raw) else i, j] for i, j in raw]
```

Result:

```
[['-', 'bla'], ['-', 'la'], ['--', 'bla']]
```

Comment: I need `raw` `[2]`'s `'='` value to change to `--` only if  an iteration of its companion string `'bla'` with `-` exists ..... so the result will be ... if any `bla` exists with the `-` ... then all other `bla`s that dont have `-` will have `--`

Comment: thanks for this. Out of curiosity, if `i` returns `['-', '-', '=']` and `j` returns `['bla', 'la', 'bla']` ... how is every `bla` asking every other `bla` (and `la`) if it has a `-` value?

Comment: oh it's the `in raw` part!

Answer (score 0):

You can set item in list comprehension ,

Your code:

```
for one in raw:
    if one[0] == '-':
        for two in raw:
            if two[1] == one[1] and two[0] == '=': two[0] = '--'
```

> convert to list comprehension :

```
[[two.__setitem__(0,'--') if two[1]==one[1] and two[0]=='=' else two for two in raw] if one[0]=='-' else one for one in raw]
print(raw)
```

output:

```
[['-', 'bla'], ['-', 'la'], ['--', 'bla']]
```